# Store the log output into a file with cmdenv-output-file

Tags: omnet++

I need to recover the content of the show log module of Omnet++/Tkenv into a file, I added in the omnetpp.ini:

**cmdenv-express-mode = false

cmdenv-output-file = log.txt**

but I have two types of problems:
1) after the simulation, I did not find the "log.txt" If I do not create it
2) and when I created it before launching the simulation under ../omnetpp-4.6/log.txt also I find it empty

I used EV << to display the content of variables that I used, I need to resolve this problem in order to analyze the traffic so how can I do that please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to start your simulation in `Cmdenv` mode. To do that go to `Run` | `Run Configurations` | select your configuration, then select `Command line` as `User interface`.
 The log file is created in `simulations` directory by default.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.

Comment: This is not working for me, the log file is not being created.

Comment: Add `cmdenv-redirect-output = true` in your `omnetpp.ini`.